# loading dynamic data using Jquery in while loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, while-loop, loading

I`m trying to load an php file to the bottom of my page without page refresh, I have a set of links within a while loop that post the specific 'lead_id' of the record clicked. This works fine with a page refresh but, I would like to do it without.

I have made a start but, my code will only spit out the first 'lead_id' in the record and not the specific one clicked.

Hope this all makes sense, here is my code:

```
      function my_onclick()
      {
       $.post("ajax/pending-admin-details.php",
      {'lead_id': $("#input").val()},
      function(data)
      {
      $("#content").html(data);
      }

      );

      }
```

and the while loop:

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($main_query))
    {
    $row[] = '<input type='button' id='input' value='{$row[0]}' onClick='javascript:my_onclick();'>'; /* i`m using a button to get the value of current lead_id */
    $row[] = "<a href='../ajax/pending-admin-details.php?id={$row[0]}' class='myClass_'><img src='../images/delete.png' alt='' /></a>";
    $row[] = "<a href='../ajax/pending-admin-details.php?id={$row[0]}'><img src='../images/delete.png' alt='' /></a>";
     $response['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
```

Any feedback would be great as this has had me in circles for 2 days now.

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies here

```
$.post("ajax/pending-admin-details.php",
      {'lead_id': $("input").val()},
```

$("input").val() will always return the value of the first input in your page.

It should be something like below.

PHP

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($main_query))
    {
    $row[] = '<input type='button' id='input' class='leadButton' value='{$row[0]}' >'; /* i`m using a button to get the value of current lead_id */
    $row[] = "<a href='../ajax/pending-admin-details.php?id={$row[0]}' class='myClass_'><img src='../images/delete.png' alt='' /></a>";
    $row[] = "<a href='../ajax/pending-admin-details.php?id={$row[0]}'><img src='../images/delete.png' alt='' /></a>";
     $response['aaData'][] = $row;
    }
```

Javascript

```
$(function(){
  $('input.leadButton').click(function(){
      $.post("ajax/pending-admin-details.php",
      {'lead_id': $(this).val()},
      function(data){
          $("#content").html(data);
      } );
});
});
```

Comment: thanks so much for your reply but, now when I click the buttons it`s not posting anything. as if the click function is not firing.

Comment: would it be better to use a link instead of a button? would that make life easier for me?

Comment: It should work. Please ensure the click event handler is triggered well. Also, using link or button is just your choice. You can use link if you like.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you have many items that the id = "input"
id need to be unique
i would call my_onclick with the value param - my_onclick(this.value) and use it directly in the post request

Comment: this now works `      function my_onclick(data)
      {
       $.post("ajax/pending-admin-details.php",
      {'lead_id': data},
      function(data)
      {
      $("#content").html(data);
      }

      );

      }
`